# BITS Download Quota

Tags: microsoft-bits, quotas

I have an application which downloads files from a server and after a certain amount of downloads in a single machine it fails, unless I run the executable as administrator (or of course debug from VS which is running as admin). I think BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service) has some sort of quota which limits how many downloads a non-admin user has and this quota seems non-existent for an admin user. Does anyone know where these settings for BITS are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These quotas can be modified with group policies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362844(v=vs.85).aspx